# No module name csv eror in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv

In python interpreter mode , i tried "**import csv**". It is working fine.
But when i import csv by using my python script , i am getting "**No modeule name csv**"

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Location of interpreter mode and python script are same

Comment: You used exactly the same python executable for both the interpreter mode and running the script? How do you run the script?

Comment: i executed python ./folder/filename". For example : python ./downloads.a.py